# Why does "draft" get used as background image instead of my image?

Tags: atbegshi

I'm trying to get AddToHook to work to add a background image and unfortunately, it always shows "Draft" in read written diagonally over the page instead of the background image image.png that I provide and which lies in the same directory. While in the end I want to have more complex logic, I reduced my problem to a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{atbegshi}%
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=20cm,inner=1.91cm,outer=3.09cm,top=2.186cm,bottom=3.537cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{background}%
\AddToHook{shipout / background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{image.png}}}%
%
\begin{document}%
x
\end{document}
```

What's wrong here and needs to be fixed so that `image.png` gets displayed?

Comment: what are you expecting the un-matched `\fi` to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I forgot to remove it when producing the minimal example. I have now removed it and the error still persists.

Comment: `draft` is because you loaded `background` package but did not specify any background using that package

Comment: you can use `example-image` in examples as it is available for tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Remove `atbegshi` and `background` as you are using new hook code, not these legacy packages, and avoid space around `/`  I also removed `inputenc` which is not needed in any format new enough to have shipout hook code.

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%

\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=20cm,inner=1.91cm,outer=3.09cm,top=2.186cm,bottom=3.537cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image.png}}}%
%
\begin{document}%
x
\end{document}
```

Comment: With that example code I get the error "! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \pgfsyspdfmark
                   {pgfid1}{4736286}{32557310}"

Comment: just run latex again, (or delete the aux file after removing background package) @Christian

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is possible to fix the opacity of your background figure?

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro well the hook just runs whatever code is supplied, the OP just used includegraphics you could adjust things using tikz or transparent packages or by adjusting the image in a bitmap editor before including

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I thinked to this but searched for a shortest way. Thanks again.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro as the image is at the back making it opaque isn't really needed, that is just a complicated way of making it lighter, I'd just edit the image before including.